# Java getContentType() doesn't work with css

Tags: java, get, mime-types

I've been trying to get the MIME type of a file and then check if the file is one of css, but it doesn't seem to be working. The snippet is:

```
String fileName = '/'+uri.getPath().substring(PATH.length());
URLConnection inputURL = getClass().getResource(fileName).openConnection();
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputURL.setUseCaches(false);
    inputStream = inputURL.getInputStream();
    String mimeType = inputURL.getContentType();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        if (mimeType.equals("text/css")) {...}
                    else{...}...
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  BTW, I doubt `getContentType()` would work off the local file system.  And ..what is your question?

Comment: What isn't working?  What's the observed vs. expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think that content type will be filled if you perform HTTP connection, e.g.

```
URLConnection c = new URL("http://foo/bar").openConnection();
String mimeType = c.getContentType();
```

In this case the content type is sent over HTTP as a header and is parsed by appropriate protocol handler. I think that this property is not initialized at all when getting so called URLConnection from resource.